# P&P RetryPolicy, what is transient exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I tried to use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.RetryPolicy; without connecting to Azure services

```
var _retry = RetryPolicyFactory.GetRetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>("Incremental Retry Strategy");
  var result = _retry.ExecuteAction(()=> InnerRequest(data));
```

the question is - what should do InnerRequest method do to RetryPolicy began work?
it should throw some sort of specified exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transient errors are detected automatically by the error detection strategies available in the **Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling** assembly (like the **StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy** in your snippet), and this will trigger the retry policy.

In reality, this is based on what you can find in the **Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.Core** assembly. Each error detection strategy in the Azure specific assembly implements the following interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an interface which must be implemented by custom components responsible for detecting specific transient conditions.
/// </summary>
public interface ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified exception represents a transient failure that can be compensated by a retry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex">The exception object to be verified.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the specified exception is considered as transient, otherwise false.</returns>
    bool IsTransient(Exception ex);
}
```

Here is an example of the **StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy** you use:

```
WebException webException = ex as WebException;
if (webException != null && (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError || webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectionClosed))
{
    return true;
}
DataServiceRequestException dataServiceException = ex as DataServiceRequestException;
if (dataServiceException != null && StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsErrorStringMatch(StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.GetErrorCode(dataServiceException), new string[]
{
    "InternalError", 
    "ServerBusy", 
    "OperationTimedOut", 
    "TableServerOutOfMemory"
}))
{
    return true;
}
StorageServerException serverException = ex as StorageServerException;
if (serverException != null)
{
    if (StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsErrorCodeMatch(serverException, new StorageErrorCode[]
    {
        1, 
        2
    }))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsErrorStringMatch(serverException, new string[]
    {
        "InternalError", 
        "ServerBusy", 
        "OperationTimedOut"
    }))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
StorageClientException storageException = ex as StorageClientException;
return (storageException != null && StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.IsErrorStringMatch(storageException, new string[]
{
    "InternalError", 
    "ServerBusy", 
    "TableServerOutOfMemory"
})) || ex is TimeoutException;
```